# User inputs multiple values and names and data is stored in text file

Tags: c++

Currently having some problems, I want the user to input data such as names and numbers and I would like all the information printed into a text file and also be able to read the info from said file when needed. Not sure what to do to make this happen the way I want,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Data{
    public:
    std::string name;
    int points;

    void Input();
    void Writetofile();
};

void Data::Input(){
    std::cout << "Enter a team \n";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Enter  average points \n";
    std::cin >> points;
    std::cout << "Enter another team \n";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Enter  average points \n";
    std::cin >> points;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    Writetofile();
}

void Data::Writetofile(){
    std::ofstream outtext ("data.txt");
    outtext <<  name  << std::cout << "    \n" << points;
    outtext.close();
}



int main(){
    Data db;
    db.Input();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem with your code is that you are overwriting the name and points of the first team when you read in for the second team. You should consider using four different variables total for the two teams.

Your second problem is that you are trying to print `points` to `cout` when it should really be printed to `outtext`.

Comment: That worked nicely thanks for that. How would I go and make sure each of the names and points are spaced and tab'd out?

Comment: In addition to printing the values of the variables, print " " for spaces and print "\t" for tabs

Comment: If this solves your problem, make sure to indicate this by clicking the check mark next to the answer.